# Microsoft's T4 template engine is not thread-safe

Tags: thread-safety, t4

Microsoft's T4 template engine is not thread safe.  We have a utility that transforms diagrams into executable C++.  Does anybody have any suggestions for how we can translate multiple files in parallel?  Ideally we'd like to develop a single process that executes multiple instances of the translator in a number of threads, but failing that we could also use multiple single processes if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We deliberately don't test the product for thread safety as its outside the scope of our support boundary.  I'd recommend that you run multiple instances of the texttransform.exe command.